# How can I get a vue directive to work in a string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

The script

```
<script>
    import { ref, reactive } from 'vue';
    export default {
      data() {
        const todo = ref('');
        const list = reactive([]);
        return { todo, list };
      },
      components: {
        navbar,
      },
      methods: {
        render() {
          console.log(this.list.length);
          return this.list
            .map((item, index) => {
              return `<div class="task"><p>${item.todo}</p><button @click="list.splice(index, 1)">del</button></div>`;
            })
            .join('');
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

The Html

```
  <div class="list-container">
    <div class="task-container" v-if="list.length" v-html="render()"></div>
    <div class="task-container" v-else>nothing in here</div>
  </div>
```

The data structure in the list array

```
{todo: 'text', checked: false},
...
```

I'm building a todo app so I'm trying to remove the selected todo from the list array without using v-for or emit but the @click directive is being read as a string. How can I get it to work?

I'd like to know how to do it this way specifically so that's why I don't want to use the other methods mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think this is best the way to handle or work and learn vue but for your information what can be done is create a method remove task and add a mounted lifecycle hook to assign the removeTask method to the window object. This way, it can be accessed from within the HTML string.

```
<script>
 import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref, reactive } from 'vue';
 export default {
 data() {
const todo = ref('');
const list = reactive(['ds', 'dsd ', 'ds']);
 return { todo, list };
 },
 components: {
//
 },
methods: {
removeTask(index) {
  this.list.splice(index, 1);
},
render() {
  console.log(this.list.length);
  const renderedTasks = this.list
    .map((item, index) => {
      return `<div class="task"><p>${item.todo}</p><button onclick="removeTask(${index})">del</button></div>`;
    })
    .join('');

  return renderedTasks;
},
},
 mounted() {
  window.removeTask = this.removeTask;
 },
};
```

By the way {{item.todo}} will be undefined as per as your logic do change it and everything will work as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work.

> Contents of v-html are inserted as plain HTML - **Vue template syntax will not be processed.** If you find yourself trying to compose templates using v-html, try to rethink the solution by using components instead.

https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-html